# How does O-Power leveling work?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I read that you need to use the lvl 1 O-Power 15 times for lvl 2 and then use the lvl 2 O-Power 30 times to get the lvl 3. Is it the same if you give them to people, I'll assume they have to be used by the person for it to count. And are you able to spam them even if the last one hasn't run out of time yet or must you wait for the timer to run out?

Answer (score 4):

The more you *use* them, the closer you'll get to the next level.

It doesn't matter whether the person uses the O-Power or not, or whether the time has run out. If you can use many in a row, all those uses will count towards moving to the next level.